# Using javascript in xslt file

Tags: javascript, debugging, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to use this script

```
function padNumber(num, len){
    var str = ''+num;
    while(str.length < len){
      str = '0' + str;
      }
      return str;
}
```

in my xlst file but I get this error when trying to debug.

> XslLoadException
>   ---------------- XSLT compile error.
>
> XmlException
>   ------------ Name cannot begin with the ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20. Line 522, position 27.

line 522 is

```
while(str.length < len){
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `<` is an xml/xslt metacharacter...it cannot appear unencoded within either type of document. it should be `&lt;`

Comment: @Rufio post an answer and later, mark it as accepted, so other will know.

Comment: @Alfabravo I was hoping Marc B would so he can get the credit

Comment: @MarcB should do it, indeed! :)

Comment: no worries, go ahead and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of redability, you can also put the Javascript code within a CDATA section. In this case you don't need to change the JS code.

However, the text in a CDATA section must not contain the string `"]]>"`. If so, this string must be split between two consecutive CDATA sections.

I believe that it is not too-likely for a typical JS code to contain that string, but one must be aware of such possibility, regardless how slim it is.

Answer (score 0):

`<` is an xml/xslt metacharacter...it cannot appear unencoded within either type of document. it should be `&lt;`